# Shouldn't big oh definition be if and if only if, not just if?

Tags: computational-complexity

This is from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications 
[image]

Shouldn't the if in that definition be an if and only if?

Say we know that $n^2$ is in O($n^2$). Then from one side of the if and only if, we know that there are constants c and $n_0$, in this case 1 and 0, such that  $n^2$ <= 1* $n^2$  for all n>= 0? 
But if we know that there are c and $n_0$, in this case 1 and 0, such that  $n^2$ <= 1* $n^2$  for all n>= 0, can't we say that $n^2$ is in O($n^2$) from the other side of the if and if only if?

The book does use if and only if. Here is an example of it [image]

Would it be more appropriate for the big oh definition to include if and only if as well?